# how a function in C can return multiple values?

Tags: c, function, pointers

In the following code, the function `avg(int i,int j,int k,int *pint,double *pfloat)` computes the average of `i`,`j`,`k` and returns the integer and float part of the result individually.  As an example, if `average = 22.45` it should return 22 and 0.45.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

void avg(int i,int j,int k,int *pint,double *pfloat)
{
  double average=(i+j+k)/3;
  *pfloat=average-(floor(average));
  *pint=floor(average);
}

int main()
{
  int Integer=0;
  double rem=0;
  avg(2,4,5,&Integer,&rem);
  printf("%d\n%lf",Integer,rem);
  return 0;
}
```

the output is 3 and 0 why ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double average=(i+j+k)/3;
```

This is an integer division. To get a useful floating point division, you can add a "." to the constant like so:

```
double average=(i+j+k)/3.;
```

making it a floating point constant (which in turn makes the division be done as floating point division).

Comment: thanks it worked I must take care about integer division